# How to avoid repetitive code in redux (ducks approach)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I've been working with `React` and `Redux` for about 3 years.
Also I use `redux-thunk` for asynchronous stuff.

And I love them a lot, but recently I noticed that almost all ducks in my project are using the same structure of actions, reducers, selectors, etc.

For example - you have an application and it has some users and transactions (or similar) lists, item details and edit functionality.
All of these lists or items have their own ducks (actions, reducers, selectors, etc).

Code below will show the problem more clearly:

```
// ACTIONS

const const setUser = user => ({
  type: types.SET_USER,
  payload: user,
});

const cleanUser = () => ({ type: types.CLEAN_USER });

const fetchUser = userId => dispatch =>
  dispatch(fetchApi(userRequests.get(userId)))
    .then(response => dispatch(setUser(response)))
    .catch(error => showNotification(error));

// delete, update, etc... user actions

// REDUCER

const userReducer = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.SET_GROUP_ITEM:
      return action.payload;
    case types.CLEAN_GROUP_ITEM:
      return null;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Code above shows the structure of `user` from `users duck` which will be almost the same for other ducks.

Is there any ways to reduce the repetitive code?
Thank you for advance!

Comment: I was about to answer with my tricks, but then I realized... I don't actually see any repetition in your example. Sure you have actions, reducers et cetera, but that's structure, not repetition; the point of using ducks so you know where to find things.

I was going to say that part of the idea with redux is being explicit, which tends to cause repetition.

Comment: If you're talking about boilerplate, I found I was happier with Redux when I started using `redux-actions`. This gives a good overview: https://codeburst.io/redux-actions-through-example-part-1-f5b2dc71de06

Comment: @Odalrick, I'm trying to say that ducks will be different only in names, but actions and reducers are almost the same for each entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I noticed that almost all ducks in my project are using the same
>   structure of actions, reducers, selectors, etc.

I never implemented the [reducks](https://github.com/alexnm/re-ducks) structure within Redux, but I did at one point find myself generating **identical** actions, reducers, etc. when managing my domain entities (e.g. Persons, Orders, Products, etc).

For instance, I always seemed to care about:

1. Are we currently fetching the entity? `isFetching`
2. Were there any errors fetching the entity? `error`
3. What's the entity's actual data? `data`
4. When was the entity last fetched? `lastUpdated`

Also, domain entities are getting added all the time, so continually copying and pasting the reducer/actions is not ideal. We need a way to **dynamically** store data in Redux, and we want that data to *always* be attached to properties like `isFetching` and `lastUpdated`.

```
{
  "entities": {
    <SOME_ENTITY>: {
      "isFetching" : null    // Am I fetching?
      "lastUpdated": null    // When was I last fetched?
      "data"       : null    // Here's my data!
      "error"      : null    // Error during fetching
    }
  }
}
```

So what if we issued an action with a string literal that will be used as a key within Redux (e.g. `products`, `orders`)? That way, we can issue whatever valid action types are available to us (`FETCH_REQUEST`, etc), and we simply need to update the `entity` key, which will automatically carve out the space in the Store for us:

```
dispatch({
    entity     : "products",
    type       : "FETCH_SUCCESS", 
    data       : [{id: 1}],
    lastUpdated: Date.now()
});

dispatch({
    entity    : "orders",
    type      : "FETCH_SUCCESS",
    data      : [{id: 2}, {id: 3}],
    lastUpdated: Date.now()
});
```

**Resulting State**

```
{
  "entities": {
    "products": {
      "isFetching" : false,
      "lastUpdated": 1526746314736,
      "data"       : [{id: 1}]
      "error"      : null
    },
    "orders": {
      "isFetching" : false,
      "lastUpdated": 1526746314943,
      "data"       : [{id: 2}, {id: 3}]
      "error"      : null
    }
  }
}
```

**Generic Entities Reducer**

```
function entities (state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_SUCCESS: // fall through
        case FETCH_FAILURE: // fall through
        case FETCH_REQUEST: {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                [action.entity]: entity(
                    state[action.entity],
                    action
                )
            });
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
};
```

**Entity Reducer**

```
const INITIAL_ENTITY_STATE = {
    isFetching : false,
    lastUpdated: null,
    data       : null,
    error      : null
};

function entity (state = INITIAL_ENTITY_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_REQUEST: {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isFetching: true,
                error     : null
            });
        }
        case FETCH_SUCCESS: {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isFetching : false,
                lastUpdated: action.lastUpdated,
                data       : action.data,
                error      : null
            });
        }
        case FETCH_FAILURE: {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isFetching : false,
                lastUpdated: action.lastUpdated,
                data       : null,
                error      : action.error
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Again, by using a generic reducer, we can dynamically store whatever we'd like into Redux, since we're using the `entity` string below as the key within Redux

```
dispatch({type: "FETCH_REQUEST", entity: "foo"});
dispatch({type: "FETCH_REQUEST", entity: "bar"});
dispatch({type: "FETCH_REQUEST", entity: "baz"});
```

Resulting State

```
{
  "entities": {
    "foo": {
      "isFetching": true,
      "error": null,
      "lastUpdated": null,
      "data": null
    },
    "bar": {
      "isFetching": true,
      "error": null,
      "lastUpdated": null,
      "data": null
    },
    "baz": {
      "isFetching": false,
      "error": null,
      "lastUpdated": null,
      "data": null
    }
  }
}
```

If this looks interesting, I did write a small lib (plug!) that does exactly what's described above:

- https://github.com/mikechabot/redux-entity
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-entity

**Live Demo:** http://mikechabot.github.io/react-boilerplate/dist/

That said, I'm not pushing that lib whatsoever, I'm just trying to describe the approach I took given the problem I had. Your action set might be totally different, in which case, you can still implement the generic pattern, but obviously have the reducer will behave differently.

Comment: Despite your warning at the beginning, you never use redux-thunk in any of your code examples.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. Cool, then I succeed, the expectation is that these actions would be dispatched via a thunk, but didn't want to muddy the waters discussing another lib. See the actual thunk usage here: https://github.com/mikechabot/redux-entity#loadentityname-promise-options

Comment: I agree this is a very clean and DRY approach. The next step would be to add thunk actions to make the HTTP requests. Since that is not related to the question and your answer doesn't have any of that code, you can remove the warning.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'll remove that piece, I agree it could be confusing.

Comment: @lux, thank you a lot for your response, code looks great and I'm going to try it.